# passing a list from jquery to a view function in django

Tags: python, jquery, django

Suppose I have the following function in my django project. getValues2() returns a list with numbers. How can I pass this numbers to my view using window.location?

```
<script>

  let getValues2 = () => $("input[name='checkb']:checked").map((i,el) => el.id.trim()).get();

  console.log('getValues2 ',getValues2())
  window.location('eprint/checked' + getValues?()

</script>
```

views.py

```
def eprint(request):

    print('eprint')
    # how to get the list from jquery? 
    print(checked)
```

Comment: You have to do an AJAX call from js to the specific url in django to receive in view.

Comment: I've got this error when trying the above: window.location is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In your JS

Also you need the JS Cookie library for CSRF if you want protection (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/; https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/)

```
<script>

  let getValues2 = () => $("input[name='checkb']:checked").map((i,el) => el.id.trim()).get();

  console.log('getValues2 ',getValues2())
  
  async function send_to_view(){
     const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
     let response = await fetch(`${url_to_eprint}`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
          'Content-type':'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
          },

     // JS sends as a string to back end
     body: JSON.strigify(getValues2)
          })
     
     let data = await response.json()
     return data
     }

     send_to_view()
     .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
     })
     .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
     })
     
  //window.location('eprint/checked' + getValues?()

</script>
```

In your views.py

```
import json
from djano.http import JsonResponse

def eprint(request):

    # post request comes in the body of the request
    print(request.body)

    # have to unpack it from a string into a dictionary
    checked = json.loads(request.body)
    print('eprint')
    # how to get the list from jquery? 
    print(checked)

    return JsonResponse({"status":"Okay"})
```

Comment: I've got a strange error: TypeError: send_to_view().then(...).then(...).error is not a function

Comment: Sorry that should have been .catch at the end.  I've updated the answer.